# how to set datepicker's end date to 20years from whatever the current date is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker. It is for birthdate. I only want to enable the date from hundred years to a certain year that is 20 years before the current year. Meaning, if the current year is 2015 then I want it to end in the year 1994.

My code is here:

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({

                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    startDate: '-1000y',
                    endDate: '1994-12-31',
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
 });
```

This is actually okay but what if the current year is 2020, the endDate is still in the year 1994.

Comment: are you using the eternicode datepicker for bootstrap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#DOB").datepicker({

                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    startDate: '-1000y',
                    endDate:'-20y',
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 20);
$("#DOB").datepicker({

                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    startDate: '-1000y',
                    endDate:d,
                    autoclose: true,
                    todayHighlight: true
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of datepicker of [setEndDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate), you can set it with js code based on your start date.